# How do I stop undefined index error from SQL query?

Tags: php, mysqli, indexing, undefined

I really have searched for the answer for this and not found a specific solution...

I've recently moved a site to a different server and the PHP.ini must be set to log errors that were not previously logged. Realise that I could suppress this error, but would rather remove the cause of it.

Database query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 0";
$retid = $conn->query($SQL) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
while($row = $retid->fetch_assoc()) {
$var1 = $row["var1"]);
$var2 = $row["var2"]);}
```

and the error in the error_log file:

> "Undefined index: var2 in /home/domain/public_html/directory/file.php
>   on line 129", with line 129 being:
>
> ```
> $var2 = $row["var2"]);}
> ```

I have read, and I get, that this error can be caused by undefined $_GET, $_POST or $_SESSION variables, but if it is thrown up each time an SQL query returns an empty value, is there a simple way to avoid building up these errors, bearing in mind that I am retrieving a lot of values with each query, so without repeating isset() arguments each time?

Thank you

Comment: In short, no.  You either need to handle the error, or live with it

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to use `isset()` but I think that may be what is needed since it looks like you're attempting to access an array element which does not exist.

```
while($row = $retid->fetch_assoc()) {
   $var1 = isset($row["var1"]) ? $row["var1"] : "";
   $var2 = isset($row["var2"]) ? $row["var2"] : "";
}
```

I also noticed that you had what looks to be an extra closing parenthesis after both closing square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

**$var2 = $row['var2'];**

Be sure that var2 is a correct name of a column on your Database table
And I don't know why you bring close bracket *)* at the end of the array